# Playwright Python: Click Specific from Multiple Button

Tags: python, playwright

I want to Automate Fill Form using `Playwright` Python version. On Playwright `NodeJS`, I've been successfully to do the desired. Only when Porting the JS Script into Playwright Python API, it's kinda different.

The Web has Multiple Button (Submit and Random) with different Name. I can achieve both Button via `get_by_role` but I have no idea to get into Specific `Submit` Button:

```
#HTML
<form method="post" action="?query=MyAPI" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <table style="width: 100%">
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td style="width: 146px">URL:</td>
                    <td><input name="url" type="text" style="width: 100%"></td></tr>

                    <tr><td style="width: 146px">&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><br>
                        <input name="Random" type="random" value="Random" style="width: 97px">
                        <span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Submit" style="width: 157px">
                            &nbsp; </span>
                    </td></tr>
            </tbody></table>
        </form>

#JS Version
await page.getByRole('button', { name: 'Submit' }).click();
```

It seems the Python Version don't have `{ name: 'Submit'}` feature, so I can only do `('button')`. I'm not sure if I left something from the API, Already tried the following things but to not avail.

```
page.get_by_role('button').get_by_text('Submit').click()
page.get_by_role('button', {'name': 'Submit'}).click()
```

**EDIT2**
It's a Public UR, Here's The Submit Button XPath: `/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/article[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span/input`

**EDIT1**:
The Button is a part of Multipart Forms, it has no `ID` so I can't find any Alternative solution.
[image: Button Image]

Comment: `name="Submit1"` is correct or should be `name="Submit"`?

Comment: Ah that's the typo on my part, it's should be "Submit" @JakyRuby

Comment: Okay, you have an answer, I would say it is correct

Comment: Okay, looks like is something different. Is this an accessible url? Or only accessible from your work? Can you post a screenshot of the button? Is the button present or have to do any kind of scroll or something? If you open the dev tool in your browser and try to locate the xpath `//input[@type="Submit"]` how many results do you have?

Comment: Thread Updated.. @JakyRuby

Comment: It is a public URL. Copying the Button XPath looks like this: ```/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/article[1]/form/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/span/input``` @JakyRuby

Comment: Alright, Update once again to Include URL and Button XPath @JakyRuby

Comment: Answer updated with a fully working example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
await page.locator('//input[@value="Submit"]').click();
```

Or

```
await page.locator('//input[@type="submit"]').click();
```

Or

```
await page.locator('//input[@name="Submit1"]').click();
```

Then you are trying with Xpath, which should be enough if that is the only submit value/name/type of the page.

Basically with `.locator` you are locating the element and then with `.click()` you are making click on that element previously located

**Fully working example**

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import time

def run(playwright):
    chrome = playwright.chromium
    browser = chrome.launch(headless=False)
    context = browser.new_context()
    page = context.new_page()
    page.goto("https://suip.biz/?act=iscloudflare")
    page.locator("//input[@name='url']").fill("google.com")
    page.locator("//input[@value='Submit']").click()
    time.sleep(10)
    browser.close()

with sync_playwright() as playwright:
    run(playwright)
```

Comment: Hi! Trying both `"Submit"` and `Submit` always result in:
```waiting for locator("xpath=//button[@value=\"Submit\"]")``` and ```waiting for locator("xpath=//button[@value=Submit]")``` and the script Ends.

Comment: Answer updated, it is not a button, it is a input, try again please

Comment: The page still the same, it's doesn't click the submit button. Have been tried on different web subdomain. I'll try to Update the Thread for clearance.

Comment: @Xavi we missunderstand each other and page confused us. Value is `Submit`, name is `Submit1` and type is `submit`. So we have a mix between capital letters, lowecase and also a char `1`. Well, now it should work

Comment: I'm heavily sorry to bother again, printing the HTML (```print(page.content())```) still indicate the submit button hasn't clicked: https://imgur.com/a/Emz2ttY

Comment: It turns out working on bash terminal instead of `WSL`. I have no Idea what's the reason but anyway Thanks. I will try to move the Tests into Windows now.